# LWJGL VBO Color affects Shading

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, directional-light

When I try to render my vbo with a directional light shader, I noticed that the color section of the vbo was messing with the shading. 
This is the format of my vbo (x,y,z,w ,r,g,b,a ,u,v ,nx,ny,nz)
The vertex color vertex points, normals, and uv coords are stored in an array, like this

```
float[] array = new float {
    0f,0f,0f,0f,
    so on and so on...
}
```

Here is the vertex and fragment shader code

```
#version 150 core
//VERTEX SHADER
in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;
in vec3 in_Normal;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat3 normal;

out Data {
    float intensity;
    vec2 st;
} Pass;

void main(void) {
    vec3 l_dir = normalize(mat3(model) * vec3(0,0,1));
    vec3 n = normalize(normal * in_Normal);
    Pass.intensity = max(dot(n, l_dir), 0.0);
    Pass.st = in_TextureCoord;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_Position;
}
```

```
#version 150 core
//FRAGMENT SHADER
uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;

in Data {
    float intensity;
    vec2 st;
} Pass;

out vec4 color;

void main(void) {
    vec4 diffuse = texture(texture_diffuse, Pass.st);
    vec4 test = vec4(1);
    color = Pass.intensity * diffuse;
}
```

The code that builds the vbo  
variables: v = vertex points, c = color data, st = texture coords, n = normal vectors.
classes: VertexData = class for organizing vertex data (the code for the VertexData class will be after this class)

```
    public void construct() {
        Manager.print(getClass(), "Normals" + Arrays.toString(n));
        int p = 0;
        int o = 0;
        int q = 0;
        vertices = new VertexData[v.length/4];
        for (int j=0;j<vertices.length;j++) {
            vertices[j] = new VertexData();
            vertices[j].setXYZW(v[p], v[p+1], v[p+2], v[p+3]);
            vertices[j].setRGBA(c[p], c[p+1], c[p+2], c[p+3]);
            vertices[j].setST(st[o], st[o+1]);
            vertices[j].setNormal(n[q], n[q+1], n[q+2]);
            p += 4;
            q += 3;
            o += 2;
        }
        FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length * VertexData.elementCount);
        for (VertexData vertex : vertices) {
            vBuffer.put(vertex.getElements());
        }
        vBuffer.flip();

        IntBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(i.length);
        iBuffer.put(i);
        iBuffer.flip();

        vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

        vboId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, VertexData.pec, GL_FLOAT,
                false, VertexData.stride, VertexData.pbo);

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, VertexData.cec, GL_FLOAT,
                false, VertexData.stride, VertexData.cbo);

        glVertexAttribPointer(2, VertexData.tec, GL_FLOAT,
                false, VertexData.stride, VertexData.tbo);

        glVertexAttribPointer(3, VertexData.nec, GL_FLOAT,
                false, VertexData.stride, VertexData.nbo);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        vboiId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiId);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
```

The VertexData class (as seen in the previous code snipet)

```
public class VertexData {

    public VertexData() {}

    public void setXYZW(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
        xyzw = new float[] {x,y,z,w};
    }

    public void setRGBA(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
        rgba = new float[] {r,g,b,a};
    }

    public void setST(float s, float t) {
        st = new float[] {s,t};
    }

    public void setNormal(float x, float y, float z) {
        norm = new float[] {x,y,z};
    }

    public float[] getElements() {
        float[] out = new float[VertexData.elementCount];
        int i = 0;

        //XYZW Elements
        out[i++] = xyzw[0];
        out[i++] = xyzw[1];
        out[i++] = xyzw[2];
        out[i++] = xyzw[3];
        //RGBA Elements
        out[i++] = rgba[0];
        out[i++] = rgba[1];
        out[i++] = rgba[2];
        out[i++] = rgba[3];
        //ST Elements
        out[i++] = st[0];
        out[i++] = st[1];
        //NORMAL Elements
        out[i++] = norm[0];
        out[i++] = norm[1];
        out[i++] = norm[2];

        return out;
    }

    public float[] getXYZW() {
        return new float[] {xyzw[0], xyzw[1], xyzw[2], xyzw[3]};
    }

    public float[] getRGBA() {
        return new float[] {rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]};
    }

    public float[] getST() {
        return new float[] {st[0], st[1]};
    }

    public float[] getNORM() {
        return new float[] {norm[0], norm[1], norm[2]};
    }

    private float[] xyzw = new float[] {0f, 0f, 0f, 0f};
    private float[] rgba = new float [] {0f, 0f, 0f, 0f};
    private float[] st = new float[] {0f, 0f};
    private float[] norm = new float[] {0f,0f,0f};

    private int v,c,t,n;

    public static final int elementBytes = 4;

    public static final int pec = 4;
    public static final int cec = 4;
    public static final int tec = 2;
    public static final int nec = 3;

    public static final int pbc = pec * elementBytes;
    public static final int cbc = cec * elementBytes;
    public static final int tbc = tec * elementBytes;
    public static final int nbc = nec * elementBytes;

    public static final int pbo = 0;
    public static final int cbo = pbo + pbc;
    public static final int tbo = cbo + cbc;
    public static final int nbo = tbo + tbc;

    public static final int elementCount = pec + cec + tec + nec;

    public static final int stride = pbc + cbc + tbc + nbc;    
}
```

Now here are some images and causes of the problem

color array  =

```
float[] {
    1,0,0,1,
    0,1,0,1,
    0,0,1,1,
    1,1,1,1
}
```

result = [image: result 1]

now I change the vertex colors, and this happens

color array  =

```
float[] {
    0,0,1,1,
    0,1,0,1,
    1,0,0,1,
    1,1,1,1
}
```

result = [image: result 2]

final example

color array  =

```
float[] {
    1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1
}
```

result = the plane appears to have flat shading even though it should be per vertex.  (I don't think I need another picture to explain this.)

I think that the problem is somewhere in the shader or vbo, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Your shaders are not using `in_Color`. So changing the color array really shouldn't be changing anything at all.

Comment: It is intentional that the in_Color does nothing, I want to find out what it is messing with that causes the shading problems @RetoKoradi

Comment: When you build the shader, do you call `glBindAttribLocation()` before linking the shader program?

Comment: Yes, also the other attributes bind  correctly @RetoKoradi